# Printing extended ASCII characters in PHP using CP437

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I need to print extended ASCII codes using [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (e.g. "É" = 144) in PHP.

Currently, `echo utf8_encode(chr(144))` will just display a question box in my console (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows).

Using `for ($i = 0; $i < 255, $i++) echo utf8_encode(chr($i))`, I see that "É" is actually 201; I presume the code page here is 65001, using [this ASCII table](http://roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/The_Characters.asp).

How do I get the string representation of ASCII character codes using CP437 in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert strings from one encoding to another. For example, to convert `chr(144)` from cp437 to utf8, you do:

```
echo iconv('cp437', 'utf8', chr(144));
// output: É
```

If you're converting *into* cp437, reverse the arguments:

```
echo iconv($originalEncoding, 'cp437', $originalString);
```